# Proxy function in PowerShell not accepting pipeline input

Tags: powershell

I've created a [proxy function](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25075.powershell-tip-to-write-a-proxy-function.aspx) for `Remove-Item`, which deletes to the recycle bin instead of permanently (using the proxy so that I can seamlessly replace the `rm` alias, without breaking 3rd party scripts).

However, it doesn't work when a file is piped into the function.  The heart of the proxy function is this:

```
if ($PSBoundParameters['DeletePermanently'] -or $PSBoundParameters['LiteralPath'] -or $PSBoundParameters['Filter'] -or $PSBoundParameters['Include'] -or $PSBoundParameters['Exclude'] -or $PSBoundParameters['Recurse'] -or $PSBoundParameters['Force'] -or $PSBoundParameters['Credential']) {
    if ($PSBoundParameters['DeletePermanently']) { $PSBoundParameters.Remove('DeletePermanently') | Out-Null }
    $scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }
} else {
    $scriptCmd = {& Recycle-Item -Path $PSBoundParameters['Path'] }
}
```

So, my custom `Recycle-Item` function is only called if `Path` is the only parameter.  So, something like `Get-ChildItem .\temp\ | rm -DeletePermanently` works just fine, but `Get-ChildItem .\temp\ | rm` has an error because the `Path` passed to `Recycle-Item` is `$null`.

I've tried passing `$Path` instead of `$PSBoundParameters['Path']` and tried splatting `@PSBoundParameters` like the call to `$wrappedCmd` above, but none of it appears to do much good.  I've copied the `params` from this function to `Recycle-Item`, to ensure that it is expecting input from the pipeline, but that doesn't seem to help either.  Some of those changes appear to pass along the file name, but not the full path, so I don't know if there's some magic inside `Remove-Item` that I need to replicate to handle a file object from the pipeline.

`Recycle-Item` is just a basic function:

```
function Recycle-Item($Path) {
    $item = Get-Item $Path
    $directoryPath = Split-Path $item -Parent

    $shell = new-object -comobject "Shell.Application"
    $shellFolder = $shell.Namespace($directoryPath)
    $shellItem = $shellFolder.ParseName($item.Name)
    $shellItem.InvokeVerb("delete")
}
```

Comment: Piping `Get-ChildItem` to `Remove-Item` will bind on `LiteralPath`, not `Path`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the provider cmdlets usually bind on `LiteralPath` when you pipe objects between them. This way allows `Path` to support wildcard globbing without the chance of passing ambiguous item paths between cmdlets.

`Remove-Item` has only two parameter sets, and they are named after their mandatory parameters, `Path` and `LiteralPath`

To solve your problem, simply check for all defined parameters that are *not* one of these two, then pass the appropriate value to `Remove-Item` based on the `$PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName` value:

```
if(@($PSBoundParameters.Keys |Where-Object {@('DeletePermanently','Filter','Include','Exclude','Recurse','Force','Credential') -contains $_}).Count -ge 1){
    # a parameter other than the Path/LiteralPath or the common parameters was specified, default to Remove-Item
    if ($PSBoundParameters['DeletePermanently']) { 
        $PSBoundParameters.Remove('DeletePermanently') | Out-Null 
    }
    $scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }
} else {
    # apart from common parameters, only Path/LiteralPath was specified, go for Recycle-Item
    $scriptCmd = {& Recycle-Item -Path $PSBoundParameters[$PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName] }
}
```

Comment: Even when piping  from `Get-ChildItem`, `PsCmdlet.ParametersSetName` is `Path` (and the check for `$PSBoundParameters['LiteralPath']` is `$false`), so I don't think that's the case here (or there's a bigger issue…)